# How to make php run a prolog program,The command works when i use on command line but not with php

Tags: php, command-line-arguments

I am trying to run a program on swi prolog through php. I am running on windows

My command are as follow

```
 $cmd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\pl\bin\swipl  -f test1.pl -g test " halt;

 exec( $cmd );
```

nothing happens  when i try to run my php code it waits for while and returns to    command  prompt on windows/system32/exe

but when i execute the same command on  cmd line i get the desired out put

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\pl\bin\swipl  -f test1.pl -g test " halt;
```

i had been trying it for last two days, any  help will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance for  all people who will give it a thought  and help   me

Answer (score 0):

Try using double-backslashes (and including "halt" within the double-quotes):

```
$cmd = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\pl\\bin\\swipl -f test1.pl -g test halt";
```

Answer (score -1):

Program Files (x86) => progra~2

$cmd = 'C:\progra~2\swipl\bin\swipl.exe -s C:\prolog\web\base.pl -g test,halt';

it's work for me