# How to setup a PrologScript

Tags: macos, prolog, swi-prolog, prologscript

I setup the following rules to find if there is a relationship between two elements:

```
directReference(A,B) :- projectReferences(A,B).
transitiveReference(A,C) :- directReference(A,B),directReference(B,C).
transitiveReferenceD1(A,D) :- transitiveReference(A,C),directReference(C,D).
transitiveReferenceD2(A,E) :- transitiveReferenceD1(A,D),directReference(D,E).
```

Can I write a PrologScript that will check all these queries for a fact?  Although I plan to use Ruby&Rake, someone is trying to do a non-interactive call from PHP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973355/how-to-make-php-run-a-prolog-program-the-command-works-when-i-use-on-command-lin) and it has not worked.  I also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973355/how-to-make-php-run-a-prolog-program-the-command-works-when-i-use-on-command-lin) and tried Kaarel's answer.  I just added a new `opts_spec`:

```
opts_spec(
    [ [opt(day), type(atom),
        shortflags([d]), longflags(['term', 'day']),
        help('name of day')]

    , [opt(goal),
        shortflags([g]), longflags([goal]),
        help('goal to be called')]

    , [opt(projectReferences), type(atom),
        shortflags([pr]), longflags(['term', 'projectReferences']),
        help('Project Reference lookup')]
    ]
).
```

I then compiled with:

`.\swipl.exe -o day.exe -g main -c "D:\DevProjects\AskJoe\Output\Sample.pro"`

And ran it with:

`./day.exe -g "day(Sunday)"`

And got error:

> ERROR: Prolog initialisation failed: ERROR: validate_opts_spec/1:
>   Domain error: `unique_atom' expected, found`term' (ambiguous flag)

My goal is to have this work:

`./day.exe -g "transitiveReference('a','b')"`

I don't like compiling a "day.exe" to run a script ([according to the docs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/PrologScript.html) this often is not necessary), but I have found no other way to pass arguments to rules.

I saw a [basic intro](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%284,%272.10.2.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/compilation.html%27%29%29) on swi-pl.org that has not helped much.  It does not explain how to make the leap from the script.sh file example to the execution of `./eval 1+2`.  In fact, the example is a comment so I'm totally lost

Comment: I believe `.\swipl.exe` is only needed for Windows systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very crude example of a PrologScript program that will read its arguments as a single goal (which may be compound), call it, and then terminate. It should work on *nix systems, and has been tested on OS X. It is just a slight variation of the [example program](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=plscript) given for using PrologScript in the SWI docs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env swipl

:- initialization main.

query :-
        current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv),
        concat_atom(Argv, ' ', Atom),
        read_term_from_atom(Atom, Term, []),
        call(Term).

main :-
        catch(query, E, (print_message(error, E), fail)),
        halt.
main :-
        halt(1).


projectReferences(valueA, valueB) :- writeln('I was called!').
directReference(A,B) :- projectReferences(A,B).
transitiveReference(A,C) :- directReference(A,B),directReference(B,C).
transitiveReferenceD1(A,D) :- transitiveReference(A,C),directReference(C,D).
transitiveReferenceD2(A,E) :- transitiveReferenceD1(A,D),directReference(D,E).
```

After saving this file as, e.g., `cli_test.pl`, you'll need to change the permissions on the file so that the operating system will recognize it as an executable:

```
chmod -x scratchboard.pl
```

After that, you should be able to call the file as as a normal executable from the command line:

```
$ path/to/the/file/scratchboard.pl 'transitiveReferenceD1(A,D).'
I was called!
```

Note:

- The goal to be evaluated is simply passed as a single argument. `query/0` will then retrieve this argument using `current_prolog_flag/2`, read it as a Prolog term, and call it.
- Since the program is not running in interactive mode, the only output will result from explicit imperatives to write out, such as occur if `catch/3` (in the body of `main/0`) is triggered by an error or if `projectReferences/2` is called successfully.

Using `library(optparse)` seems advisable for more complicated cli interface, but is not necessary for your stated aim of merely querying goals in a file.

I understand that getting the PrologScript approach to work on Windows is somewhat different. A bit of information can be fond here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/PrologScript.html

Comment: I'm using OSX.  I copied the code and saved it as `script3.pl`.  Then I execute it in bash with `sudo ./script3.pl 'transitiveReferenceD1(A,D).'` and get `command not found`.  I ran `which swipl` and get `/usr/local/bin/swipl` so I tried `#!/usr/local/bin swipl` and got `command not found`.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey hmm... the only thing I can think of right off the bat: did you give the file executable permissions using `$ chmod +x script3.pl` ?

Comment: Oh! So it's working! Great! I'll add that bit of instruction to my answer, and suggest that change to the SWI docs too. I've run into this same stumbling block in the past. It is far too easy for those who write documentation and provide tips to forget how many "obvious" details are only obvious after repeated use.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this all working and then after a few runs everything just stopped.  I started getting 'permission denied bad interpreter' errors. All I can say is that it has something to do with the hashBang.  The workaround for me was to create a shell script around the call to swipl:

`shellscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
swipl -s script4.pl 'projectReferences(A,D).'
```

Then I continued using aBathologist's example, but just took off the hashBang:

```
:- initialization main.

query :-
        current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv),
        concat_atom(Argv, ' ', Atom),
        read_term_from_atom(Atom, Term, []),
        call(Term).

main :-
        catch(query, E, (print_message(error, E), fail)),
        halt.
main :-
        halt(1).


projectReferences(valueA, valueB) :- writeln('I was called!').
directReference(A,B) :- projectReferences(A,B).
transitiveReference(A,C) :- directReference(A,B),directReference(B,C).
transitiveReferenceD1(A,D) :- transitiveReference(A,C),directReference(C,D).
transitiveReferenceD2(A,E) :- transitiveReferenceD1(A,D),directReference(D,E).
```